# Production-ready DTD or XSD for describing restaurant menus?

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

My current problem could best be solved by an industry standard DTD or XSD describing restaurant menus. I don't *think* such an industry standard exists.

I'm hoping at least one organization has already published such a DTD/XSD, even if it's only for their own proprietary use.

My goals are to store a wide range of arbitrary restaurant menus in XML format, with multi-lingual support, multiple-currency support, and various pricing methodologies (per person, per pound, per kilo, etc), among a few other more trivial requirements.

Pointing me to related schemas is also welcome (perhaps for order-taking, record keeping, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at http://openmenu.com/specification.php? They don't have any licensing info up there that I noticed, but if it looks good you could try to sweet talk them about it would be good for them to release it under a OS license to promote their work as a "industry standard."

On 2nd look they might just be calling free form xml a spec...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a Google search for `"restaurant menu" xml schema` this returns some irrelevant links (with "menu" being so overloaded), but there are a few that might lead you in the right direction.

Comment: More or less, yes. I've seen some discussion about the idea, and a few "early" designs, but nothing I'd be happy to put into production.